# why the strip() removing values which are not mentioned

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = ['Japanese', 'Painting Books', 'Management Textbooks', 'science book (Books)']
 
strp_l=[]
for i in string:
  a=i.strip('(Books)').strip('Textbooks').strip('Books')
  strp_l.append(a)
print(strp_l)
```

I got output as

```
['Japan', 'Painting ', 'Management ', 'science book ']
```

but I tried to get output like

```
['Japanese', 'Painting ', 'Management ', 'science book ']
```

Comment: have you read the documentation of `strip()`?

Comment: The characters inside the brackets are going to be used one at a time and stripped. So `Japanese` will get stripped to `Japan` because of `Textbooks` The characters `e` and `s` are part of `Japanese` so it strips them out. Similarly for all other items.